# Eclipse- Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer error while creating new project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am not able to create a new Dynamic Web Project in eclipse indigo. I am getting the following error while creating new one.

> Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer

I have java compiler version as 1.7 and SDK version 1.7.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my eclipse is pointing to jre version 1.7 , but somehow while creating dynamic web project it is taking java verion 4. i solved it by changing it through configuration>modify>java version to 1.7, in the same panel.

Answer (score 79):

This is late answer. But may help to other. If you are using `Maven` based project. You just include following code in `pom.xml` file. It can be resolved.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Update:** Similarly if you are using jdk version 1.8 just include it in your  `<source>` and `<target>` tags.

Comment: I'd say this is the correct answer, as Maven uses 1.5 as default compiler independently of the version you have in your JAVA_HOME or eclipse (source: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)

Comment: Very helpful answer!

Comment: Also it is good way of maintaining this in pom for deployment on multiple machines

Answer (score 34):

Just Change "the dynamic web module version" to 2.5 and than change it back to 3.0 and the error disappears. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 24):

Answer was correct :),
But slightly need a correction.

--> Enable Java compiler to 1.7

--> Facet check java (do not check Dynamic module)

--> Last step check Dynamic module

:)...

*after you enable java compiler to 1.7 then go to facet then first check **java** instead of Dynamic module. Then it will allow you to check the Dynamic module.*

Comment: Perfect answer.. Error is due to uncheck of JAVA. It has nothing to do with version.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this might work for you guys, but here is my case:

1. My java version lists as java 1.8 with `java -version` but I got the same same error on eclipse.
2. Later I changed the dynamic web module version to 2.5. the error notification disappeared.
3. Then again I changed my dynamic web module version to 3.0 and the error did not show up; and I was able to create the project.

I dont know the reason though.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using maven

just add code to pom.xml mentioned by  and 
**Project> properties> Maven> Update Project**
It works

Comment: I am not sure how but this surprisingly worked for me after i simply Updated the project from `Project> properties> Maven> Update Project`.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have several installed java versions on your PC, and your Eclipse is started based on old version.

In command line *java -version* command shows default one or even first installed one, which is saved somewhere in registers, and it is not always that which is used by your applications. (As example, I have only 1.7 installed physically now but *java -version* shows old one 1.5)

You may try next: right click on **Eclipse shortcut**, chose Shortcut tab, and change Target field so that it **run with -vm argument pointing on that Java version you need**:

*"D:\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe"*

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, see what i did:
first screen Shot:
[image]

go and click New Runtime>Apache Tomcat v7.0 (for me)>Finish 
[image]

now the error has been removed [image]

Answer (score 1):

if there is any different JDK version (more then one jdk )installed previously uninstall all of it. then install fresh one jdk (latest ) n to configure java environment see follow this link....

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE&list=PL484D73FA74A11AC9

now follow following steps:

1. right click on project >properties >project fact
2. check on java by selecting version on its right side with dropdownlist.
3. check on Dynamic Web Module with its version 
      (remember that different version of this requires different version of 
       TomcatServer so installed one step old version of tomcatServer)
4. now click apply n ok.

There are different reason for this problems but this is the most cases. is not solved contact at sanlama21@outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Configuration->Modify->java->**select java version 1.6 or later on ..Error will disappear.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps in the link  and it worked for me  [solving-dynamic-web-module-3.0 requires java 1.6 or newer in maven projects](http://qussay.com/2013/09/13/solving-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-in-maven-projects/)

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps and all errors will be gone -

1- Right-click on your project folder 
2- Click properties
3- Click Java Build Path 
4- Click Libraries 
5- Select JRE system library
6- Click the edit button on the right 
7- Select alternate JRE
8- From the drop-down select the installed JRE and all errors will be gone

Answer (score 1):

I needed to modify the configuration and create a new runtime for tomcat. Not sure what happened to the original installation, but creating a new one did the trick.

[TomcatConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twEQg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because **Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer**. (*Dynamic Web Module version 3.0 refer Serverlet 3.0*)
You should 
* Download and install newer JDK ([JDK 1.8u20](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html)) 
* Download and install newer Eclipse: [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Luna (4.4)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar)
[image]

Update:
* Check `JAVA_HOME` Environment variable
 or 
* Edit `eclipse.ini` file (tutorial: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini ) find section: `-vm value`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ...

file >> New >> Dynamic web project  >> Enter project name >> Change 'Dynamic Web module version' from 3.0 to a lower version ,say 2.5, then  change it back to 3.0 , the error message disappears . I think the initial error message that says it requires  java 1.6 or above is a bug in Eclipse Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

1. Go to .settings File
2. Then add project Facet "`File.org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core`"
3. then add the following file

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> -
>
> ```
> <fixed facet="jst.java"/>
>
> <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
>
> <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
>
> <installed facet="jst.java" version="1.8"/>
>
> <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.4"/>
>
> </faceted-project>
> ```

save it and refresh the project
4. then try to add Dynamic web module in project facets.

Answer (score 0):

select properties then select project facet then if java option is not checked then check the Java option after that check dynamic web module option

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple java version inside C:\Program Files\Java - this issue will happen. So move other JDK versions to some other folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).