# Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer ECLIPSE JEE - Dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I downloaded Eclipse. When I tried to create a new Dynamic web project I got this error:

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909611/eclipse-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-error-while-creating) is different from this.

I installed Eclipse JEE, and I am trying to create a Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: Open Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs. You should have a JRE definition checked. What is in the 'Name' column for the entry that is checked? Also, open Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler. What is the value shown for 'Compiler compliance level'?

Comment: the value shown by **Compiler compliance level** is 1.8

Comment: Your problem may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909611/eclipse-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-error-while-creating?noredirect=1&lq=1 so try the suggestions there, and advise whether any of them worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you are not specifying any Target Runtime and the default configuration probably is on an older version.

You can try to configure a new Runtime Environment like below and select it to create your project after with it.

[image: Add a new runtime]

Then you select your server (the example is done with Tomcat but other servers should be similar):

[image: select server]

Then select the JRE associated to your runtime:

[image: select jre]

And finish by creating your Target runtime and use it, it should solve the problem:

[image: done]

Hope it helped!

**PS:**

You can also configure your Target runtime in *Windows->Preferencces->Server->Runtime Environments*