# Everything right, but still appearing -> Type Dynamic Web Module 4.0 requires Java 1.8 or newer

Tags: java, maven

Seems that my project is correctly configured, but Eclipse still showing the error below:

**Dynamic Web Module 4.0 requires Java 1.8 or newer.**

[image: Dynamic Web Module 4.0 requires Java 1.8 or newer]

I have tried everything already, Clean, Build, Update Maven Project, Maven clean, Maven Compile...

**Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
        version="4.0">
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <error-page>
            <error-code>404</error-code>
            <location>/404.xhtml</location>
        </error-page>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.mccsis.utils.LoginFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/logado/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>AdmFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.mccsis.utils.AdmFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>AdmFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/logado/adm/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>server</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
            <param-value>california-#{preferences.theme}</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/primefaces-california.taglib.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>ttf</extension>
            <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>woff</extension>
            <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>woff2</extension>
            <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>eot</extension>
            <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>eot?#iefix</extension>
            <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg#exosemibold</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg#exobolditalic</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg#exomedium</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg#exoregular</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
            <extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>
            <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
        </mime-mapping>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.mccsis.visao.configuracaoTemplate.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        </filter-mapping>
         <listener>
             <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
         </listener>

    </web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>br.com.mccsis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mc_c_sis</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.18</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.18</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>6.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.17</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.7.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.46</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

**org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faceted-project>
      <fixed facet="java"/>
      <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
      <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
      <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
      <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.0"/>
      <installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>
      <installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>
    </faceted-project>
```

[image: Project Facets]

[image: Java Build Path]

Please, If I miss something, tell me.

**UPDATE**

**Java Compiler**

[image: Java Compiler]

Comment: Do you run eclipse with java8?

Comment: Check the _Java Compiler_ page for Java 8 settings in _Project Properties_

Comment: Look the Java Compiler page Updated above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found solution here [Eclipse- Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer error while creating new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909611/eclipse-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-error-while-creating)

Adding the next lines to the pom.xml helped in my case

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *pom.xml* file add these properties:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Here I use **JDK-17**, but you should change it to installed version of *JDK*.

And after that, right click on your project and choose **Maven > Update Project...**

Then you can select newer versions of *Dynamic Web Module*.